# MAX DATE from multiple lines

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a SQL Query which returns multiple lines for multiple Invoice numbers AND Invoice Line items, but from which I just want the record with the latest date for each invoice+line item combo. I've tried this, but obviously MAX Date isn't possible!

```
SELECT *
   FROM (
SELECT
   CD.NAME,
   DSF.SALES_DOC, -- EACH SALES_DOC COULD HAVE MULTIPLE LINE ITEMS   
   DSF.LINE_ITEM,
   MD.MATERIAL_DESC,
   TO_DATE(MMF.RECEIVED_DATE_KEY,'YYYYMMDD') AS RECDATE  -- EACH 
                                SALESDOC/LINE COULD HAVE MULTIPLE DATES
FROM
    MART.DAILYSALES DSF,
    MART.MARKET MMF,
    MART.MATERIAL MD,
    MART.LINESTATUS ALS,
    MART.CUSTOMER CD
WHERE
    DSF.SALES_DOC = MMF.SALES_DOC
    AND DSF.LINE_ITEM = MMF.LINE_ITEM        
    AND DSF.MATERIAL_ID = MD.MATERIAL_ID
    AND ALS.LINE_STATUS = MMF.LINE_STATUS
    AND CD.SOLDCUSTOMER = DSF.SOLDCUSTOMER_KEY
    AND TO_DATE(MMF.RECEIVED_DATE_KEY,'YYYYMMDD') > 
TO_DATE('20170601','YYYYMMDD')
) 
WHERE
    MAX ( TO_DATE(MMF.RECEIVED_DATE_KEY,'YYYYMMDD'))

GAV INC 100001 01 WIDGETS 20170101
GAV INC 100001 01 WIDGETS 20170501  
GAV INC 100001 01 WIDGETS 20170801  - Want this line only as latest date
GAV INC 100001 02 WIDGETS 20170101
GAV INC 100001 02 WIDGETS 20170501  - Want this line only as latest date
GAV INC 100002 01 WIDGETS 20170301
GAV INC 100002 01 WIDGETS 20170501  
GAV INC 100002 01 WIDGETS 20170901  - Want this line only as latest date
```

Comment: Do a GROUP BY, and use max()!

Comment: pls. tag DB Version

Comment: Using Toad for Oracle Pro v11.

Comment: Tried both  GROUP BY MAX ( TO_DATE(MMF.RECEIVED_DATE_KEY,'YYYYMMDD'))

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY NAME, SALES_DOC, LINE_ITEM, MATERIAL_DESC`.

```
SELECT
   NAME,
   SALES_DOC,
   LINE_ITEM,
   MATERIAL_DESC,
   MAX(TO_DATE(RECEIVED_DATE_KEY,'YYYYMMDD')) AS RECDATE
FROM
    DAILYSALES
    JOIN MARKET USING(SALES_DOC)
    JOIN MATERIAL USING(MATERIAL_ID)
    JOIN LINESTATUS USING(LINE_STATUS)
    JOIN CUSTOMER USING(SOLDCUSTOMER_KEY)
WHERE
    TO_DATE(RECEIVED_DATE_KEY,'YYYYMMDD') > TO_DATE('20170601','YYYYMMDD')
GROUP BY
    NAME, SALES_DOC, LINE_ITEM, MATERIAL_DESC;
```

If that doesn't work, you could use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT
   NAME,
   SALES_DOC,
   LINE_ITEM,
   MATERIAL_DESC,
   RECDATE
FROM (
    SELECT
       NAME,
       SALES_DOC,
       LINE_ITEM,
       MATERIAL_DESC,
       MAX(TO_DATE(RECEIVED_DATE_KEY,'YYYYMMDD')) AS RECDATE,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SALES_DOC, LINE_ITEM
                          ORDER BY RECEIVED_DATE_KEY DESC) AS RN
    FROM
        DAILYSALES
        JOIN MARKET USING(SALES_DOC)
        JOIN MATERIAL USING(MATERIAL_ID)
        JOIN LINESTATUS USING(LINE_STATUS)
        JOIN CUSTOMER USING(SOLDCUSTOMER_KEY)
    WHERE
        TO_DATE(RECEIVED_DATE_KEY,'YYYYMMDD') > TO_DATE('20170601','YYYYMMDD')) t
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated !

Comment: Happy to help! If you found it useful, you might consider [accepting or upvoting my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).